# auto abbreviating JLabel

Tags: java, swing

Anyone written a JLabel (extension/util/??) that automatically abbreviates the contents depending on it's preferred/visible size?

much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't JLabel abbreviate text that can't fit by default?  
This code displays only "The quick brown fox jum..." on my install:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JLabel Test");
        frame.setSize(160,120);
        frame.getContentPane().add(
            new JLabel("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.") );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: haha .. i had just noticed that - i had mistaken a bug for JLable not working how it obviously does... sorry for the stupid question!!

Answer (score 0):

For improved swing, before writing your own extensions, I recommend to check [SwingLabs](http://swinglabs.org). In particular there is a cool [JXLabel](http://swinglabs.org/hudson/job/SwingX%20Weekly%20Build/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXLabel.html) (although it's not clear what you want that the regular JLabel has not)

Comment: i had a look at their website and there's nothing there too impressive. not sure what relevance your answer has whatsoever.

Comment: Well, your question was asking for something that was already available in the regular JLabel, so it wasn't really clear what you were looking for. SwingLabs **is very** impressive (maybe the JXLabel is not where they shine best), so it must be the first place to look at when you need something more than plain vanilla Swing.

Comment: sorry, i'm not having a go at you - but i did look at the website and some content was not available (404) while what was available was honestly not that helpful/impressive - so i'm not sure of the relevance....